# Running for loop to read xlsv

Tags: python-3.x

I have a excel on US airports, I need to get their zip codes in the adjacent column. 
Using Google geocoding, I could read their zip codes individually. But now I need to run the FOR loop to read all the entries. My excel file has only 1600 rows with names of Airports in a single column.

This is my code:

```
data = get_data("/Users/shreyaagarwal/Desktop/Airport and zipcodes.xlsx")
import json
print(json.dumps(data))

for element in row:
    g= geocoder.google(element)
    print (g.postal)
```

This code reads until 5 rows and then stops
This is result:

```
None
None
None
None
54015
None
```

Which is not correct!
Please help.
I need to get the zip codes adjacent to the airports in the excel. Is it possible?

Comment: What is 'row' in your for loop? What does 'print element' inside your loop give you?

Comment: Row is each row in the excel. Element gives me the value inside each cell. for instance my excel sheet has list of airports in a single column:      Putnam County Airport
Dowagiac Municipal Airport
Cambridge Municipal Airport
Door County Cherryland Airport
Shoestring Aviation Airfield
Eastern Oregon Regional Airport
Tyonek Airport
Riverton Regional
Montrose Regional Airport
Clow International Airport
Kenosha Regional Airport} I need to get to each cell and place the zip code adjacent to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the elements in 1 row. You need to wrap that in a for loop for each row  i.e.

```
for row in rows:
   for element in row:
```